# System.TypeInitializationException - The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, nullreferenceexception, typeinitializationexception

I have been working on an application for about two and a half years now and last month we went live and published our .NET application. The application is a WPF application that uses .NET version 5.0.17 and its main purpose is to do calculations for separation vessels. It consists mostly of UserControls, connected to ViewModels that use “calculation runners” to asynchronously do long calculations for these vessels.

Since the release we have been getting TypeInitializationException almost daily. I spent these two and half years working on the application almost daily, but never encountered the issue once, while working on four different devices. It also happens inconsistently and across multiple classes. We make backup’s of the project right before the crash to replicate the issue, but the exception doesn’t happen again when replicating the steps.

Below are the specifics for the exception. The exception happens inside a Task.Run block and throws a TypeInitializationException with a NullPointerException as inner exception, but it never contains any information about what class actually contains a null value. I also tried wrapping the code in Task.Run() within a try-catch block, but that also results in the exact same exception, which leads me to think the exception is inside the Task.Run.

I have been breaking my head over this issue the past month but I can’t figure out what’s wrong for the life of me.

**System.TypeInitializationException**

```
The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.
   at MySep.Studio.DesignCalculationRunner.Run(Int32 vesselIndex, Boolean openProjectFile)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at MySep.Studio.DesignCalculationRunner.Run(Int32 vesselIndex, Boolean openProjectFile)
   at MySep.Studio.DesignCalculationRunner.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<RunAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at MySep.Studio.DesignCalculationRunner.RunAsync(Int32 vesselIndex, Action chainMethod, Boolean openProjectFile)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__140_0(Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
MySep.Studio
```

**the inner exception:**

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
(without any further information on where the exception happens)
```

**the code:**

```
internal static async void RunAsync(int vesselIndex, Action chainMethod = null, bool openProjectFile=false)
{
    //ParamName is undefined now, should be vessel tag or so, "Vessel" is fine for now
    DockHelper.ToggleSpinner(true, "Running design calculations...");

    //Await project
    Project proj = await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        return await Run(vesselIndex, openProjectFile);
    });

    //Refresh application
    DockHelper.RefreshAllControls(vesselIndex);

    //After calc method
    if (chainMethod != null) chainMethod();

    //Event bus after calc
    EventBus.Publish(Events.PerformanceCalculation);

    //Wait for spinner
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(400);
    });

    //Toggle spinner
    DockHelper.ToggleSpinner(false);
}

internal static async Task<Project> Run(int vesselIndex, bool openProjectFile=false)
{
    //Create param
    MySepParam mySepParam = new MySepParam();
    mySepParam.LiquidLevelSetIndex = 0;
    mySepParam.SectionName = "Vessel";
    mySepParam.VesselIndex = vesselIndex;
    mySepParam.BEAccessCode = Global.BEAccessCode;
    mySepParam.OpenProjectFile = openProjectFile;

    //Set globals
    Global.ProjectName = Global.Project.Name;
    Global.VesselIndex = vesselIndex;

    //Write sentry breadcrumb
    SentryHelper.AddBreadcrumb($"Calculation - Design");

    //Run
    var allResults = Global.Project.VesselsResults;
    var vesselResult = DesignCalculationHelper.DesignCalculation(Global.Project.Vessels[vesselIndex], mySepParam).VesselResults;
    if (allResults.Count <= vesselIndex)
        allResults.Add(vesselResult);
    else
        allResults[vesselIndex] = vesselResult;

    await Task.Delay(1);
    return Global.Project;
}
```

I tried:

- Wrapping everything in try-catch blocks.
- throwing the InnerException instead of the exception in Jira.
- Searching for classes that could possibly contain null values.

But all to no avail

**Edit**

Someone in the comments suggested it might be a duplicate of [this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989240/what-is-and-how-to-fix-system-typeinitializationexception-error) This is not the case as this user can’t run his application because of a generic TypeInitializationException with an InnerException explaining what static variable is missing. In my case the message is “The type initializer for '' threw an exception” and does not further explain what part of the application causes the exception. It looks more like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852965/typeinitializationexception-the-type-initializer-for-module-threw-an-except), but that one is from 12 years ago and uses .NET 2.0. The InnerException is also different and says “The C++ module failed to load during appdomain initialization.”

The suggested solution here was “Your customer needs to get their machine stable again, then reinstall .NET”, however I have a hard time believing it’s an unstable .NET version that is causing this, since we have a lot of users that have encountered this issue once or twice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is and how to fix System.TypeInitializationException error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989240/what-is-and-how-to-fix-system-typeinitializationexception-error)

Comment: Hey @ASh, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately not, my problem is the opposite. I have never encountered the issue on my own device. But can see that other people have on Sentry. However this does give some more insight into the issue, so thank you.

Comment: @SepVrij I agree with Ash that it is a duplicate. Anyhow, I'd start adding a bunch of null checks like for example on `Global`, `Global.Project` etc. Especially static variables and just see if they throw in production.

Comment: Are you able to execute it withou the `async` ?

Comment: @sommmen (IMO) It's not a duplicate since it's not just a TypeInitializationException but one that throws "The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception". The link ASh provided does look like my exception and I can recreate code that throws such an error but it doesn't contain the <Module> part.

Comment: @JamesWiseman I am able to execute it both with and without. The issue seems to occur at very random times and I am not able to reproduce it.

Comment: I think i'm getting where you're coming from, see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852965/typeinitializationexception-the-type-initializer-for-module-threw-an-except

Comment: Seems like some call somewhere goes wrong on some machines, maybe due to faulty .net install, missing dlls,or wrong .net framework dll or something... Perhaps add some try-catches so you know what part of the app fails and you can do a more defined search.

Comment: @sommmen Yeah I've read that one a few times and seems to be related. I was hoping this would be a different issue since I don't use the Oxygene Pascal compiler. It also has a different InnerException: "The C++ module failed to load during appdomain initialization."

Comment: @sommmen I've tried wrapping all the parts in seperated try-catches but the error always stays the same, just an empty NullReferenceException with no line where it happens. A faulty .NET install could be possible but out of the 20 people that work in our company maybe 5 or 6 have experienced the issue once. That seems to much for a faulty install. Do you think it might be the .NET version?

Comment: @SepVrij i understand it gives the same error, but i'd be more interested in the specific location or what module throw, because this seems to be some .net fx call somewhere that faults (and thus it could be a certain dll that is too old or something like that) so for example if you know its a certain Usercontrol, or its a certain api call into visual studio you can google for issues with that part of the app. Regarding a fauly .net install, i doubt it would be that. Perhaps log and make a breakdown of what os/net versions are used or something like that?

Comment: it does not seem to happen all the time, so it could also be something like timing, but it seems to be a specific call or part of the app that throws, its hard to see as-is

Comment: Why do you have an `async` method that returns `void` instead of `Task` (this is probably why you have no stack traced)? Why are you calling `Task.Run` instead of just awaiting the method calls directly?

Comment: There's no happy story to tell here.  There's a module initializer in PresentationCore, it initializes a bunch of undocumented C++ code.  Such code can fail with a null pointer exception, just like C# code can.  It gets reported as an NRE at runtime, but without any details where it came from.  Your user needs to use a utility like DebugDiag to capture a minidump at the time the exception occurs.  And submit it as evidence in a support case with Microsoft so they can diagnose the cause.  Having IT staff analyze these machines to see what they have in common would be another way.

Comment: To be clear, nothing you can do to help them, other than advice them how to move ahead.  Pretty much like what I'm doing now :)